# passing parameters into controller's action skipping action name

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes, controller, action, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm looking for the way to shorten the URL for getting some from DB. I've got Homecontroller and `writing` action, which adds rows to DB and each of them has UID. There is also `search` action which finds the record in DB anв renders a view.

So I use `localhost/Home/writing` to add a record and `localhost/Home/search/3456` to search a record by UID.

Is there any way to pass UID (3456) into controller's action skipping action's name, so to search a resord I can use `localhost/Home/3456` or even `localhost/3456`?

I've tried

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "default-action", 
    "{controller}/{id}", 
    new { action = "search", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

and

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "default-action", 
    "{id}", 
    new {controller = "Home", action = "search", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

but got nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a route constraint:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Search",
        "{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Search" },
        new { id = @"\d+" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Now:

- `localhost/Home/writing` will hit the `Writing` action on `HomeController`
- `localhost/3456` will hit the `Search` action on `HomeController` and pass it `id=3456` as parameter

The numeric constrained we defined for the `{id}` route token is required in order for the routing engine to disambiguate between the search and the default route patterns (since action names cannot start with a number). It assumes that your identifiers are numbers.

Comment: @versus, if this post helped you solve the problem you were having make sure to [mark it as answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking on the tick next to it.

Comment: Done! sorry, I'm a newbie here, and can't give "Useful_points" to your answwer :(